# Embed JSON element in HTML element using Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to retrieve the raw JSON used to construct a template and have it populate in a textarea element.

The structure of the JSON is an array of JSON objects containing three properties which fills out my template fine. What I can't figure out is how to take that raw JSON element on each iteration and display it within a textarea.

My description of the issue may be a bit obtuse so hopefully the JSFiddle example describes this better.

**Javascript**

```
function MyViewModel() {
    this.model = [{
        "Key": "c1243328-4796-46c0-bb32-017d5a1ebdd4",
        "UserId": "02ad61b1-d416-46d4-98ac-d5f6c2b7d104",
        "Name": "\"old.txt\""},
    {
        "Key": "265c23ea-2d2a-459e-9f51-32837e058d01",
        "UserId": "02ad61b1-d416-46d4-98ac-d5f6c2b7d104",
        "Name": "\"sample.dwg\""}];
};

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

**HTML Template**

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'template', foreach: model}"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="template">
    <p>
        <span data-bind="text: Key"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: UserId"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
    </p>
    <p><textarea data-bind="text: ???"/></p>
</script>​
```

I would like to see the actual JSON element in the textarea and I am not sure what is required to accomplish this.

The above running in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thewiseguy99/E9zX9/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `$data` [contextual binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) property which represents the current viewmodel and the `ko.toJSON` helper method to output it as a string:

```
<textarea data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"/>
```

See in action in [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/E9zX9/3/)